# How to change git url for app on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

When I run "git remote -v" from Terminal I get the following:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:obscure-taiga-9581.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:obscure-taiga-9581.git (push)
origin  http://coastguard-quiz.herokuapp.com/ (fetch)
origin  http://coastguard-quiz.herokuapp.com/ (push)
```

I want to replace the "git@heroku.com:obscure-taiga-9581.git" part. How do I do that?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is push to coastguard-quiz repo which is on heroku, so that when you `git push heroku` it updates the caostguard-quiz.herokuapp.com.

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:coastguard-quiz.git
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how it'll affect Heroku, but you can change the path in .git/config

Comment: Thanks for responding Ethan. Could you please explain in more detail how to do that? Sorry I'm very new to all this. I'm aware that .git is a hidden folder in my main project folder but not sure how to access any files/configs inside of it.

Comment: There's a file inside your .git directory called config. 

Inside that file, you'll find: [remote "heroku"] and you can change that remote's url field to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. For those who have never accessed files in .git directory before you run "cd .git" to get inside of the hidden .git directory and then run "open config" that should open config file in text editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `"git@heroku.com:obscure-taiga-9581.git"`

git remote rm heroku

then add new remote repository

```
git remote add heroku git@github.com:your_nick/name_of_repo.git # this is good to copy paste from your github account
```